# Team member cannot clone repo from BitBucket?

Tags: git, repository, clone, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am quite new to BitBucket/SourceTree, infact I am quite new to GIT!

I created a BitBucket account couple of days ago, created a private repo and invited one other user (with WRITE permission).

On my machine, I opened SourceTree, generated SSH key, added SSH key to BitBucket, voila, repo cloned, everything works.

My friend (whom I invited to share the repo with) can edit/view/download the repo contents on BitBucket. However, he is unable to "clone via SourceTree"

He is on Windows 7.

So far, he has tried:

1. generated public SSH keys, adding SSH keys to his BitBucket, nothing happened
2. generated private keys with passphrase, etc etc, nothing happened
3. I sent him my public-key file, he tried loading that, nothing happened

It appears to be a "SSH authentication" error but we have run out of options as to what to do! Any suggestions advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you can try using the HTTPS URL provided by BitBucket, which looks something like https://user@bitbucket.org/owner/project.git 
This method is password-based, and allows you to work without having to configure SSH access.

**Edit**
I just checked on the BitBucket website and realised that their "Clone in SourceTree" button doesn't allow you to select the HTTPS URL. To do so, start from SourceTree, click on "Clone / New", and copy the HTTPS URL in the "Source Path / URL" Field.

Comment: That kinda works with the HTTPS however the URL we are now using (which seems to be working) is quite simple  HTTPS:///www.bitbucket.org/owner/project.git

Comment: Where to specify the password to do this?

Comment: This is not a solution... This is an insecure work around.

Comment: It's no more insecure than typing your password when logging in to BitBucket, all communication happens over HTTPS